# Google SAML Response XML

Tags: python, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, google-sso

I am trying to setup Google as SP and my own database as IDP. I have configured my GSuite account with my login and logout URL and google is redirecting to them perfectly.
But after SAML request from google, I try to generate SAML response, I am getting ***G Suite - This account cannot be accessed because the login credentials could not be verified.***

Below is my SAML Response XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE samlp:Response [
    <!ATTLIST samlp:Response ID ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="n7dff0678252c667b24cae2be1925746166d0906c" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-01-12T12:05:23Z" Destination="https://www.google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com/acs"><saml:Issuer>google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com</saml:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#n7dff0678252c667b24cae2be1925746166d0906c"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>bcUzuWbYSccmvCXN25mXaW7u1qw=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>6L7UmVK/76MeVupEUKSLySrLEntcDrI0CPad3TQEN3D7BDKgoRpfWXWiQElsk64i
H0c1iCfrDEApoAFe17iORowmJlghumTJzzCXfPhcvpecj2UmikivULyM87eKNVGa
kEG4ZXS/1OqWwZ3HpVtHK3VPYPQY1FnvAnAEeZNj3zRgv3hyuAHXaUcAEHVYbLGa
uvkbQrOSlVafHMPEj++go3AS6B6QFxonVGYbf5FE+txkKocyudLBf94IJl6Gd3o0
VCMj7UewcXm1MweXOZyh+M6AXTt125QQGZFPJWiTMDTjFWIKzGXdh/Rau/B1S1KU
BG4VbE0C8goQfGwbKhQ3jg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIEBzCCAu+gAwIBAgIJANPE0ekUwoLyMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGZMQswCQYD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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status><saml:Assertion Version="2.0" ID="gf860726b83c8386cdd3d89131223f535cb51f615" IssueInstant="2017-01-12T12:05:23Z"><saml:Issuer>google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com</saml:Issuer><saml:Subject><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:email">admin@demo.mediaagility.com</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="nhchacfajpmpbahlbbdoneoncpicjheamlgooigp" Recipient="https://www.google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com/acs" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-13T12:05:23Z"/></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-01-12T12:05:23Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-13T12:05:23Z"><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience>google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestriction></saml:Conditions><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-01-12T12:05:23Z" SessionIndex="gf860726b83c8386cdd3d89131223f535cb51f615"><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement></saml:Assertion></samlp:Response>
```

I used python-saml python package to sign my saml response:-

```
from onelogin.saml2.utils import OneLogin_Saml2_Utils
bPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))), "keys")
cert = open(os.path.join(bPath, "cert.pem")).read()
key = open(os.path.join(bPath, "private_key.pem")).read()
signedData = OneLogin_Saml2_Utils.add_sign(samlXML, key, cert)
return signedData
```

Any help will be much appreciated.and I am using python language.

Below is my Google SSO configuration
[image: Google SSO configuration]

Comment: I ran into that message before. What happened to me was that I returned the response to Google Suite's login request endpoint. In order words, that endpoint is used to receive AuthnRequest when Google Suite takes the IdP role. I don't have the environment here to check what endpoint I turned to use though

Comment: I am posting using below form: 
        <form class="login-form" name="saml-form" method="post" action="https://www.google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com/acs" >
            <input name="SAMLResponse" type="hidden" value="{{SAML_RESPONSE}}"/>
            <input name="RelayState" type="hidden" value="{{RelayState}}" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
where SAML_RESPONSE is above complete xml

Comment: @Thuan, is there something wrong with my form ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to base64 your response. One way to test your code is to test it against another SP that can give you better error message such as SimpleSamlPhp. Anyway, below is a response for Google Apps that works for me. Two things I noticed: your response doesn't have Issuer and audience restriction is different.

```
    <samlp :Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
       xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
       ID="_e8d051da91c78463aab61868a575a99bbba1266a2b"
       Version="2.0"
       IssueInstant="2017-01-09T04:43:37Z"
       Destination="https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com/acs"
       InResponseTo="dcbcmhemepohapphnloohdmmmimbmanljcnmkabp">
  <saml:Issuer>myissuer</saml:Issuer>
  <ds :Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds :CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <ds :SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <ds :Reference URI="#_e8d051da91c78463aab61868a575a99bbba1266a2b">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds :Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <ds :Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds :DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <ds:DigestValue>G5fRiUNgyak14pNsjas8UCWfzUQ=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>Sz8Aa9oEnOiWW4MscHdgTjJxtstzYo2IGdVBZC3jlIIBYUYS1HPdva5M9pfdL+wJohnZ4id+xfeW+xDVQmL0/ivgFR7PRBWQicGmcbPxMhynPkS3JUbUIDKuqwcKWqKJ2aOdyxr2MBOQjRrGwOG/Q1b55j6q4mBJKqW0JmKgeYZOW6Af9R3D/oyLKvG/IHNiptSsPbwuz+QLPtglbwjYocRpXyV4oW267CJleqtlXt9gprVERXtaKEAx1LVNLFiy8YYwuBVjUMljxvqfkvu9ygsaOTDyUE6X8u1U6wXhEALvX+bL9aqOtj3OS7XAHyzlHDyxuqAybqHsFkUWO66d7g==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
blah blah
      </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp :StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
  </samlp:Status>
  <saml :Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        ID="_03d8531d7a6344272153841942e3a4c3aa298ff0ce"
        Version="2.0"
        IssueInstant="2017-01-09T04:43:37Z">
    <saml:Issuer>myissuer</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml :NameID SPNameQualifier="google.com/a/mydomain.com"
            Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:email">info@mydomain.com</saml:NameID>
      <saml :SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml :SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-09T04:48:37Z"
              Recipient="https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com/acs"
              InResponseTo="dcbcmhemepohapphnloohdmmmimbmanljcnmkabp" />
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml :Conditions NotBefore="2017-01-09T04:43:07Z"
          NotOnOrAfter="2017-01-09T04:48:37Z">
      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>google.com/a/mydomain.com</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml :AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-01-09T04:43:37Z"
          SessionNotOnOrAfter="2017-01-09T12:43:37Z"
          SessionIndex="_f2e2722e24cb27743c12de9ca41765554aa3186214">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml :Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/emailaddress"
            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml :AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">info@mydomain.com</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
  </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
RelayState
https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1
```

Comment: I am able to send create a valid SAML Response, but now I am getting "G Suite - This account cannot be accessed because the login credentials could not be verified." Can you please help on on this. I am updating my question with valid SAMLResponse.

Comment: That is a good step ahead :) Maybe https://support.google.com/a/answer/2463723?hl=en can help.

Comment: I am still not able to figureout what is wrong with my saml response and still getting could not login credentials. 
I am updating question with details. Is is due to I have configure Google SSO with https://127.0.0.1/login (localhost url) instead of my domain demo.mediaagility.com ?

Comment: I would suggest you remove the DOCTYPE and ATTLIST elements from the response, add inresponseto to the response element, and check if you upload the correct certificate to your GSuite admin console. Finally, check if you are returning a correct email account which has access to GSuite. Other than that, I run out of ideas :)

Comment: I am using Gsuite Administrator account to sign in as SSO. How I am doing this is , I send a request to google.com/a/demo.mediaagilty.com/acs and then google redirects to my localhost with SAMLRequest and RelayState keys, and I display login page there, I use the GSuite administrator account to sign in, validate the user from openldap and return above saml response.

Can we use administrator email to sign in this way from SAML or we need a generic user account ?

Comment: the account usage seems right. How do you send a request to google.com/a/demo.mediaagilty.com/acs? I usually test it by accessing a google service, e.g. https://mail.google.com/a/mydomain.com which starts the SSO process.

Comment: I sent a get request to https://google.com/a/demo.mediaagility.com/acs from my local machine(no public ip, it is running on 127.0.0.1:443) and then google redirect to me with SAMLRequest parameter . and I display the login page to user. Also I have configured the https://127.0.0.1/login url in SSO login url field in google SSO. Will it work with 127.0.0.1 ip. It redirect to this ip is just fine. Doe sit check for public ip when it receives the post saml response.?

Comment: I am still not able to get it correct and still facing problem with error 'login credentials could not be verified. I am using my localhost(127.0.0.1 for my domain demo.mediaagility.com and generated the certificate from my local machine). I am worried if the certificate generated on localhost for domain demo.mediaagility.com are being rejected by google sso when posting the saml response and giving me above error.

Comment: I can't comment about localhost usage because AFAI can recall Google requires a resolvable domain so I decided to test it against an internet-facing test site. In addition, I tried to login to a Google service such as the mail.google.com/a/mydomain.com above so that Google Suit knows where to redirect a user to after authentication is done. That's all I know :)